# Assign a unique number in a range randomly

Tags: sql, t-sql, random, range, unique

I need to assign a list of employees a unique number from 1 to 1000 (or however many employees there are). The numbers can't repeat and need to be in a random order against the employee list. The numbers also need to be regenerated each week so the employee is assigned a new number.

I have tried to use the following, however the script is slow and it returns the same number for all employees.

```
DECLARE @Random INT;
DECLARE @Upper INT;
DECLARE @Lower INT

SET @Lower = 1 
SET @Upper = 1000 
SELECT @Random = ROUND(((@Upper - @Lower -1) * RAND() + @Lower), 0)
select personnum, firstnm, lastnm, (SELECT @Random)
from person
```

Can anyone shed any light on how to do this?
Thanks

Comment: Why do you need a random order?

Comment: The random order is so the employees can be sorted and assigned a limited number of shifts per week by without any favouritism.

Comment: @Withdalot . . . for that problem, you might just consider "ORDER BY newid()"

Comment: Thanks Gordon but I still need a number the app can use to sort and select the employees by.

Comment: Is it a requirement that no employee wins the same number two weeks in a row?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Works on mssql server 2005+

```
select personnum, firstnm, lastnm, row_number() over (order by newid()) randomnumber
from person
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a function for it.  Here is one we use:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_GenerateUniqueNumber]()
RETURNS char(10)

AS 
BEGIN
    --DECLARE VARIABLES
    DECLARE @RandomNumber VARCHAR(10)
    DECLARE @I SMALLINT
    DECLARE @RandNumber FLOAT
    DECLARE @Position TINYINT
    DECLARE @ExtractedCharacter VARCHAR(1)
    DECLARE @ValidCharacters VARCHAR(255)
    DECLARE @VCLength INT
    DECLARE @Length INT

    --SET VARIABLES VALUE
    SET @ValidCharacters = '0123456789'   
    SET @VCLength = LEN(@ValidCharacters)
    SET @ExtractedCharacter = ''
    SET @RandNumber = 0
    SET @Position = 0
    SET @RandomNumber = ''
    SET @Length = 10
    SET @I = 1

    WHILE @I < ( @Length + 1 )
        BEGIN
            SET @RandNumber = (SELECT RandNumber FROM [RandNumberView])
            SET @Position = CONVERT(TINYINT, ( ( @VCLength - 1 ) * @RandNumber + 1 ))
            SELECT  @ExtractedCharacter = SUBSTRING(@ValidCharacters, @Position, 1)
            SET @I = @I + 1
            SET @RandomNumber = @RandomNumber + @ExtractedCharacter
        END

    RETURN @RandomNumber
END
```

To use it do something like this:

```
SELECT personnum, firstnm, lastnm,dbo.fn_GenerateUniqueNumber()
FROM person
```

You can modify the parameters and allowed values to ensure it is the type of number you want.

Comment: Which is why I ended with "You can modify the parameters and allowed values".  You just need to remove the non-numbers.  This is a very flexible function.

Comment: Is there a way to add it to the select statement as this is going to be run via simple middleware that won't support the function?

Comment: I guess I should have asked where you are running it.  You didn't specify. I believe @t-clausen.dk method will work.